# Platform exception error doesn't catch error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I'm developing a flutter app with Google admobs rewarded video ad. What I have done is at starting of the app i.e., at init function I loaded the video and the ad will shown after a button action. After the ad finished playing if the user again clicks on a button then `Platform exception error`. I also used try catch statements still the error is not catched by them. The error caused is here.

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ad_not_loaded, show failed for rewarded video, no ad was loaded, null))
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What IDE do you use? VS Code?

Comment: @intraector VS Code

Comment: This kind of bug will need more context, can you post some of the code? Sounds like you are not waiting for the ad to properly finish or you are trying to call the ad again.

Comment: @temp_ I added some code.

Comment: Are you waiting for `.load` to complete? Also does `.load` have a `.catchError` call? If there is a `.catchError`, you can pull the error and see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug of VS Code, just untick 'Uncaught Exceptions'

[image]